# Get all the numbers between min and max values from mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a tables with 3 column:

```
serial_nbr    min_Serial_nbr    max_Serial_nbr 
    1              1                  4
    2              5                  7
    3              8                  11 
    4              12                 15
```

I want to get all the numbers >= 1 and <= 15 (like 1,2,3,4,5,6 until 15).

Here's the query I tried:

```
 SELECT CEILING((RAND() * MAX_SERIAL_NBR) + 1) AS WIN_NUMBER FROM 
 RTL.SERIAL_MBR 
  UNION 
 SELECT CEILING((RAND() * MIN_SERIAL_NBR) + 1) AS WIN_NUMBER FROM 
 RTL.SERIAL_MBR
```

but I just get a random number like 1,3,6,11.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why you want to do it in SQL. Do it in php

Comment: I don't get it. You're using `rand()`. Isn't a `random number` kind of expected?

Comment: I suppose `$range = range(1,15)` is not what you're looking for?!

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: For what purpose you have used RAND()? If you didn't required random numbers.

Comment: Yes RAND() is not required you must specify the upper and lower limits.

Comment: yeah, i can't get the number between upper and lower limit from 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

With php you can do:

```
$pdo->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE column >= 1 AND column <= 15');
```

Comment: It is the static way.  isn't?

Comment: why to try with static fix value?

Comment: with mysql can't ?